# Asking password after command ssh server2

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, rhel5

I have two server
server1
server2

want to login server 2 from server 1,I added  both pub key (ssh_host_rsa_key.pub) in one another server in .ssh/authorized_keys.

when i run #cd /etc/ssh;ls -ltr able to see below file
sshd_config
ssh_config
moduli
ssh_host_key.pub
ssh_host_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to login without asking password through ssh server2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host keys `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` are stored automatically by `ssh` in `known_hosts` files; they are not intended to be managed by the user.

The `authorized_keys` is intended for user identity files. What you really want to do is to use [ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) to generate an identity file representing you:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
```

Two identity files are generated: the private key `id_ecdsa` and the public key `id_ecdsa.pub`. Copy the public key into server2's `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you created a passphrase for your identity files, that's what you will be using from now on. Otherwise, your login will be password-less.

Comment: Thanks Fabio.Can we create the pub key for mutilple users as you mentioned above and it will not affect other pub key right?

Comment: That's correct, you can create identities and store them into different files, giving you many possibilities: Using the same identity to login as different users in server2 and other servers, or having a separate identity for each user and each server, daisy-chaining logins into other networks, logging in from different clients using an identity from each client, etc. Please consider accepting my answer to gain reputation, thanks.